# HDFS random read and disk IO

Tags: hdfs, disk-io

When we read a single byte from HDFS file, does it mean a full HDFS block gets read from the disk somewhere on the cluster (assuming no caching involved)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

This is affected (may be not exclusively) by `dfs.datanode.readahead.bytes` parameter, which defaults to `4MB` in hadoop `v2.2.0`